# Extract a module from a magento installation to a zip?

Tags: magento-1

Is there tools/software can extract a module installed in a magento (includes DB stables, js script, layout, phtml, xml) back to a zip file?

Does this tool exists?

Comment: You can use the Magento connect packager.  
You just need to create a package and provide the files and folders included in the module. The downside is you have to know them and their location.

Comment: how about sql setup script? how to convert sql dbtable to setup script?

Comment: every module should have an install/upgrade script. so you should include that file in the archive.